# How to NOT shrink text within menu bar on Mobile mode using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm working on this Menu bar which has a toggling function working just fine. But my issue is that when user clicks on the Menu bar Icon (While on Mobile mode) the Menu bar opens from left to right and if user clicks on it again the Menu bar closes but it shrinks the text inside of it. Basically, I would like to just close it **WITHOUT** shrinking the text and **also have the text move to the left when closing**. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or missing in my jquery code please? Thank you in advance!

Here's the **DEMO** that works just fine, but with the **shrinking text** issue

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown').hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass('open');
 }, function(){
   $(this).removeClass('open');
 });


$('#nav-toggle').click(function(){

 $(this).toggleClass('active');
$(".navbar-collapse").animate({width:"toggle"});

});

  $('#mobile-subnav').click(function(){
   if($('.second-nav .navbar-left').css('display') == 'block'){
    $('.second-nav .navbar-left').slideUp(function(){
     $(this).addClass('not-visible');
   });
    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Open Submenu');
  } else {
    $('.second-nav .navbar-left').slideDown(function(){
     $(this).removeClass('not-visible');
   });
    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close Submenu');
  }
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>

body .navbar-nav.navbar-right li.login-desktop a:hover,
body .navbar-nav.navbar-right li.login-desktop a:active,
body .navbar-nav.navbar-right li.login-desktop a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
body .navbar-nav.navbar-right li.signup-desktop a {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
body .navbar-nav.navbar-right li.signup-desktop a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
body #nav-toggle span,
body #nav-toggle span:before,
body #nav-toggle span:after {
  background: #fff;
}
body .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background: #000000;
  border: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
body .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu .divider {
  background-color: #343434;
}
body .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
body .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #A11D2E;
}
body .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu .open {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
body .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 0px;
}

.navbar-default {
  background:#000000;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -73px;
  margin-top:60px;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
  padding: 12px 20px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  background: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #333;
  background: none;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #DB1D1B;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > a:visited,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #DB1D1B;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #DB1D1B;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
  color: #DB1D1B;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding: 11px 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  margin: 16px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav-open .navbar-default {
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
}
.nav-open .navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-left li:first-child a,
.nav-open .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-open .navbar-nav.navbar-right li.signup-desktop a i {
  display: none;
}
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  display: none;
}
#nav-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}
#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 25px;
  background: #2E353B;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -8px;
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -8px;
}
#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .theMainPicture{display: none;}

  #scrolltopbtn{display: none;}
  body.nav-open {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 235px;
  }
 
  body #nav-toggle {
    display: block;
    color: red;
    z-index: 4;
  }

  .sliding-picture{
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .slide{
    z-index: 999;
  }

  body #nav-toggle.active {
    position: absolute;
  }
  body .navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    width: 240px;
    background: #202630;
    box-shadow: inset -10px 0 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    top: 0px;
    left: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    border-top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  body .navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  body .navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-left li:first-child a {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  body .navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-left li a {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  body .navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-nav > .open > a {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  body .navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-right {
    width: 240px;
  }
  body .navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a.user-link-desktop:hover,
  body .navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a.user-link-desktop:active {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  body .navbar-nav.navbar-right li.signup-desktop a {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  body #home-content {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .home .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu,
  .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: 0px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .home .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu .divider,
  .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu .divider {
    border-color: #090E16;
  }
  .home .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu li a,
  .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu li a {
    color: #ccc;
  }
  .dropdown .dropdown-menu .divider {
    background-color: #494E56;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    background: #fff;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
    border-color: #494E56;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .main-nav-row {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: -30px;
  }
  .second-nav {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .second-nav .navbar-left {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .second-nav #mobile-subnav {
    display: block;
  }
  .second-nav .navbar-right {
    margin-right: -15px;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
  }
  .second-nav .navbar-right input {
    width: 170px;
  }
  .second-nav li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .second-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav li {
    border: 0px;
  }
  .second-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav li.dropdown.open a.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .second-nav .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #333;
  }
  .second-nav .dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #333;
  }

  #sidebar .block.list a.block-thumbnail .small-box-overlay {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  #sidebar .block.list .block-contents {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-brand img {
    width: 140px;
    height: auto;
  }
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 140px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 13px;
  }
}

    </style>
</head>
<body id="app-layout">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style = "position:fixed;">
        <div class="container">
            <div style = "padding-top:8px;background:#000000;" class="navbar-header">
                <a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="" alt=""/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style = "z-index:-1;">
                <ul style = "padding-top:8px;" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="#">My account</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">This is link 1</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">someLink</a></li>
                    </li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">This is link 2</a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Course 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Course 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">This is link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add a `width: 240px;` to `ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left`

Comment: put it inside the media-query block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add the following rule in your css, inside the media-query.

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left {
  width: 240px;
  float: right;
}
```

Additionally, your markup is mismatched in quite a few places. Checkout: https://jsfiddle.net/0ghv6the/1/ for my changes.